# How do I get a pickaxe that can break dirt and grass?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I tried to give myself a diamond pickaxe which I expected could destroy dirt. Then I tried altering it to break both dirt and grass, it wouldn't work.

Here is the command I tried first:

```
/give SapphireloveJen diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["dirt"]}}
```

Here is the one I tried later:

```
/give SapphireloveJen diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["dirt","grass"]}}
```

My Minecraft version is 1.14.30.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Arqade! What is exactly the command that you tried? What is the result that you expect?

Comment: Hi Jourmie, here is the command I used this command because I thought it was funny:   /give SapphireloveJen diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["dirt"]}} I did get it but when I tried with both dirt and grass, it wouldn't work.

Comment: You told the game to only let you break dirt with that pickaxe and then you were surprised that you couldn't break grass with it? Wasn't that the point all along?

Comment: no sorry I wasn't clear, I tried it with dirt only first, but then tried changing the command to  make it break both dirt and grass

Comment: Also Jourmie I was kind of only testing out so not necessarily just those things when you updated it so I guess we are both right and wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirt block and grass block are considered two different block types in Minecraft, thus have different ids.

Try the following:

```
/give SapphireloveJen diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["dirt", "grass"]}}
```

If you want to add more block types, here is a list of the ids: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_data_values